# SQLAlchemy Cross Apply in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy, cross-apply

I'm attempting to replicate the following query using Flask SQL Alchemy and Python 2.7:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[MyFunction] (MyTable.ColumnValue)
```

I'm not sure if this even possible. If it is possible, can someone point me to documentation or code snippet that would get me going in the right direction?

Not sure what other information to give, so if you need more info, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think you can join on a User Defined function.  It should be because you can't have a foreign key on a function, and in order to join using SQLAlchemy you have to have a foreign key or a defined relationship.

Hopefully someone else could shed some light on this if they see it differently.

Comment: You are correct, with the current system. You cannot do this. Thanks